# gettingerror as Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php

```
<?php
{
session_start();
include "dbconnect.php";
$target1=$_SESSION['target1'];
echo $target1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM userpictures where pictures = $target1";

$result = mysql_query($query);

var_dump($result); 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
echo $row;  
    {
    $_SESSION['picid1']=$row['picid'];
    //$_SESSION['picid1']=$row->picid;

    echo $_SESSION['picid1'];

    }
}
?>
```

it is returning me the output as
images/2101.jpgbool(false)
Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

it is giving the target1 but not the picid
please help.

Comment: You need to check the right-hand bar, quote your variable or - even better - switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Added `'` - `pictures = '$target1'`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM userpictures where pictures = '$target1' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
{
   $_SESSION['picid1']=$row->picid;       
   echo $_SESSION['picid1'];

}
```

Use,

```
$row->picid;
```

instead of

```
$row['picid']
```

**Note:** Use mysqli_* fucntions or PDO instead of mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Comment: but i dont need the whole array, i just need current picid single picid, thats why i am using where clause mr.dragon

Comment: In you have only one row which is associated with `pictures = '$target1'` then you get only one row!

Comment: `echo $query;` after query statment and copy and paste into phpmyadmin or command line in mysql and check what is the results you have ?

Comment: Update my answer, please check